# jQuery slideshow to only show navigation after timer

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

How can I make a jQuery slideshow only allow the user to navigate to the next slide after a set period of time?

Do I have to throw in a setTimeout somewhere or is there an existing slideshow with this capability out there?

I can't find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way you would do this is you would advanced to the next slide, hide the navigation control for going to the next slide and then after a setTimeout(), you would show the navigation control.

You don't show us your HTML so here's some manufactured HTML to illustrate:

HTML:

```
<button id="nextSlide">Next</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#nextSlide").click(function() {
    var button = $(this);

    // go to next slide here

    // hide next button
    button.hide();

    // after 2 seconds, show the button again
    setTimeout(function() {
        button.fadeIn(500);
    }, 2000);

});
```

Or, it could be done entirely with jQuery animations like this:

```
$("#nextSlide").click(function() {
    // go to next slide here

    // hide next button, delay, then dfade in
    $(this).fadeOut(200).delay(2000).fadeIn(500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.Deferred promise method to manage the end of the cycle

```
$('#myslidebutton').click(function () {
    mybutton = $(this);
    mybutton.hide(); //or whatever to not allow a click
    $('div').animate({ // whatever your slide show part is
        "opacity": "0"
    }, 1000).promise().done(function () {
        //after the animation
        mybutton.delay(1000).show();
    });
});
```